# Taskkill multiple instances of same application process running in task manager with python

Tags: python, windows, taskkill

If there are multiple instances of notepad.exe running in task manager, taskkill should kill the exe with python. If only one notepad.exe process is present then taskkill must not be done.
How can I do this ?

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im notepad.exe")
```

Comment: You can iterate over all processes with [psutil](https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to launch OS commands, using `os.system()`, you might consider launching this command:

```
tasklist /FI "imagename eq notepad.exe"
```

If the result contains only one result, do nothing. Else, kill them.